# Reading locale info from Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, clipboard-interaction, clipboarddata

using .NET Clipboard API you can write following code:

```
//dataObject - instance of IDataObject, received from Clipboard
if (dataObject != null)
{
    if (dataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Locale))
    {
        var data = dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Locale);
        var locale = AsInt(data);
        if (locale.HasValue)
        {
            return new CultureInfo(locale.Value);
        }
     }
}

int? AsInt(object data); - my method which tries to read `Int32` value from `MemoryStream`
```

The question is why I always get `en-US` locale even when my PC's locale is ukrainian?
I cannot get it, I thought Windows OS puts current locale info into clipboard when copy operation is performed? Isn't it?

**UPD:** I need to know locale of the object inside the clipboard, if it is possible

**UPD2**: My PC's locale is **uk-UA**, PC's UI locale is **en-US**, FAR Manager puts something different to clipboard (value 1024, which cannot be recognizsed as valid locale identifier). So it seems to be Excel2010 problem.

Comment: Are you trying to get your systems current locale designation or the locale of the object inside the clipboard?

Comment: Locale of the object inside the clipboard

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps the problem is on the side of the code that put it on the clipboard, and not on your side. Does this also happen if the object on the clipboard is something you put there yourself (with the desired locale)?

Comment: Tested applications - Windows Notepad, MS Excel 2010. Didn't tired to put data by myself

Comment: Looking for some reason for this, I am leaning to the same though presented above by @M-Peror where the application putting the info on the clipboard may be the culprit.

Comment: You both are right, FAR Manager puts '1024' as culture identifier to the clipboard (which, cannot be recognized by .NET as a valid identifier for some reasons). So, why the hell excel puts not my current culture? And how can i retrieve it?

Comment: 1024 seems to be a special Office quasi-locale identifier meaning "No Proofing", see [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221435)

Comment: Do you have the Ukranian Office language pack installed?  This question belongs at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, see my answer if you are still interested in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/857e7ff1-e864-40e9-a108-a6314b1f4dff)